# How Can I get index of element from list

Tags: android

I have a problem with my loop. This is loop:

```
for(String element: listOfSBPData){
            date1 = (String) element.subSequence(0,2);
            date2 = (String) tvDateFrom.getText().subSequence(0,2);
            if(element.contains(tvDateFrom.getText())){
                for(int i = 0; i<7; i++)
                if(date1.contains(date2)){
                    listOfSBPDataToPlot.add(element);
                    listOfSBPToPlot.add(listOfSBP.get(element.//here I want to get id my element))
                }
            }   
        }
```

I have a problem to get Id for `"element"` in place in code where I put comment. How I can get index of this element? I need index of this element because I have other table and I want to get element with the same index.

Comment: use good old for (int i ...

Comment: so if I use that way I can't get index of this element?

Comment: unless you add your own counter, no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int index =0;

for(String element: listOfSBPData){
        date1 = (String) element.subSequence(0,2);
        date2 = (String) tvDateFrom.getText().subSequence(0,2);
        if(element.contains(tvDateFrom.getText())){
            for(int i = 0; i<7; i++)
            if(date1.contains(date2)){
                listOfSBPDataToPlot.add(element);
                listOfSBPToPlot.add(listOfSBP.get(index));
            }
        }   
        index++;
}
```

Comment: Just be careful if you end up removing or adding things to the list you are iterating over